# Handle exceptions in a loop with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have a list of objects and for each object, I need to hit external API using the RestTemplate. To do that I am using the for loop with try-catch block. In case external API does respond with 4xx, 5xx status code I need to create the list of errors and throw the custom exception which is handled using the exception handler to send client-friendly messages which also send the email notifications. The requirement is to remove the try-catch block and hit the external API in a loop and create the list of errors and check if the error list is not empty throw the exception and send all the error messages at once in the email notification using the exception handler method handleApplicationErrors. But I believe when any exception will occur for loop will be a break and I will not be able to create a list of error messages without a try-catch block, is there any possible way to do it?

```
public void method() {
    List<Objects> objects = fetchObjects();
    List<String> errorList = new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++) {
      try{
        hitExternalApi(object)
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        errorList.add("Error Message")
      }
    }
    if(!errorList.isEmpty()) {
       throw new ErrorDTO(Status.BAD_REQUEST, errorList);
    }
}

  @Override
  public void hitExternalApi(Object object) { 
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(object, httpHeaders);
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Void.class);
  }

@ExceptionHandler(ErrorDTO.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleApplicationErrors(NativeWebRequest request, ErrorDTO error) {
    notificationService.sendNotification(error.getErrors());
    Problem problem =
        Problem.builder()
            .withStatus(error.getStatus())
            .withTitle(error.getMessage())
            .withDetail(error.getErrors().toString())
            .build();
    return create(error, problem, request);
  }
```

Comment: how does 'hitExternalApi' method looks like? you need add functionality in this method to throw exception when response.getStatusCode() is not 2xx(http code for success).

Comment: Hello @ProgrammerBoy, It is a normal rest template exchange method call without any try-catch block. If I throw the exception in this method I will not be able to create a list of error messages and sending a single notification for it.

Comment: You should also be checking the status code of the ResponseEntity returned by `exchange`. But why do you say you have a requirement to remove the try-catch block? It is necessary to handle any exceptions thrown by `hitExternalApi`.

Comment: Yes, I can manage it using the status code and based on try-catch block within for loop or in a method. But one member of the team has suggested removing the try-catch block and creating the list of error messages for all the objects that we send to external API and sending the email with the whole list. So I was eager to know whether it is possible to do the same without using a try-catch block. If I remove try-catch and do it based on the response status code, it will throw the exception for 4xx, 5xx and will not be able to create a list of error messages for all objects in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the for loop inside a function and and call the exception after calling that function.

refer the following example for a better understanding:

**BEFORE**

```
public class ExceptionInLoop{
public static void sampleMethod(){
  String str[] = {"Mango", "Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Oranges"};
     try {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
           System.out.println(str[i]);
           System.out.println(i);
        }
     }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        System.out.println("Exception occurred");
  }
  System.out.println("hello");
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
  sampleMethod();
}}
```

**AFTER**

```
public class ExceptionInLoop{
public static void print(String str) {
  System.out.println(str);
}
public static void sampleMethod()throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException   {
  String str[] = {"Mango", "Apple", "Banana", "Grapes", "Oranges"};
     for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        try {
           print(str[i]);
           System.out.println(i);
        } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(i);
     }
  }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
  try{
     sampleMethod();
  }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
     System.out.println("");
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve what you are asking for by moving the try-catch block down to the `hitExternalApi` method and let this return a boolean or a DTO if you need to pass any information. The for-loop can then just check the return value of `hitExternalApi` and populate the `errorList` if needed.
Modified code example:

```
public void method() {
   List<Objects> objects = fetchObjects();
   List<String> errorList = new ArrayList();

   for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
     if (!hitExternalApi(object)) {
       errorList.add("Error Message");
     }
   }
   if (!errorList.isEmpty()) {
     throw new ErrorDTO(Status.BAD_REQUEST, errorList);
   }
 }

 public boolean hitExternalApi(Object object) {
   httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(object, httpHeaders);
   try {
     restTemplate.setErrorHandler();
     restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Void.class);
     return true;
   } catch (Exception exception) {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

Per default, (so when using the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler`), the invocation of `restTemplate.exchange(...)` will throw some kind of `RestClientException` for 4xx and 5xx responses, so you will either need to handle this exception somewhere or provide your own `ResponseErrorHandler` and build logic around that.

Answer (score -1):

You can just create an extra object for controlling the  flow

```
public class ApiResponsePojo {
    private HttpStatus status;
    private String message;
    private String data;
}
```

You can use a class like this and modify it to the way you want to store the messages. you can check if there's any error through status and populate a message in the status

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).